# How to close a QDialogueBox automatically using pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

Here it is my sample code when my condition is false i want to close the dialog box i used object.close() method, but its didn't work properly.so can anyone please help me how to close the dialog box in this case

Given bellow is my sample code:

```
global startNow
if fileName:
            a = True
            while startNow:
                print startNow
                if startNow:
                    print 'showing dialog boxxxxxxxxxxxxx',startNow
                    self.dialogmsg = QtGui.QDialog()
                    self.dialogvbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.dialogmsg)
                    self.dialogmsg .setGeometry(550,400,300,100)
                    self.msglabel = QtGui.QLabel("Please Wait A Minute The Data is Processing" )
                    self.dialogvbox.addWidget(self.msglabel)
                    self.dialogmsg.exec_()
                    print 'box is therrrrrrrrr'
                    a = False
                    # self.dialogmsg.close()

                if not startNow:
                    print startNow,'closeeeeeeee'
                    try:
                        print 'try  closinggggggg'
                        self.dialogmsg.close()
                    except:
                        print 'except closing erorrrrrrrrrr'
                        pass
                    break
```

Comment: From only this code, you will end the dialog by startNow flag.But once the dialog shows,I have no idea where you change the flag.If you connect the dialog and other funcitions for changing the flag to False,this dialog will be closed.

Comment: Dialog.exec_() develop new loop, if you don't stop the loop,`a = False` is not executed.Usually,programmer set the actions on the dialog for closing the dialog with Signal&Slot.

Comment: i change the flag in thread class